# ComboBox - Set selected item by enum name

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, enums

I initialize my ComboBox with Enum values like so:

```
private void initPrioritys()
{
    m_PriorityComboBox.DataSource = Enum.GetNames(typeof(MPriority)).ToArray();
}
```

After that I want to update the selected item:

```
m_PriorityComboBox.SelectedItem = (MPriority)i_Data.Priority;
```

This is my enum:

```
public enum MPriority
{
    Critical,
    High,
    Important,
    Medium
}
```

The problem is that no matter what value i_Data.Priority has the selected item stays the first index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change it to `m_PriorityComboBox.SelectedItem = Enum.GetName(typeof(MPriority), (MPriority)i_Data.Priority);`

Since your data source is an array of strings -- because of `Enum.GetNames(typeof(MPriority)).ToArray();` -- not enums, you need to reference each item as a string.

Answer (score 2):

You set `DataSource` to array of `string` so `SelectedItem` needs to be string as well:

```
m_PriorityComboBox.SelectedItem = i_Data.Priority.ToString();
```

or set `DataSource` to enum values instead

```
m_PriorityComboBox.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(MPriority));
```

and then `SelectedItem` will be of `MPriority` type and

```
m_PriorityComboBox.SelectedItem = (MPriority)i_Data.Priority;
```

will work

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use the object as `DataSource` with `Name` and `Value` properties.

```
m_PriorityComboBox.ValueMember = "Value";
m_PriorityComboBox.DisplayMember = "Name";
m_PriorityComboBox.DataSource =
                Enum.GetNames(typeof(MPriority))
                    .Zip(
                          Enum.GetValues(typeof(MPriority)).Cast<MPriority>(),
                          (s, i) => new {Name = s, Value = i }
                        )
                    .ToList();
```

then you can easy set the `SelectedValue` to achieve your goal.

```
m_PriorityComboBox.SelectedValue = i_Data.Priority;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe can help to set the SelectedValue instead of SelectedItem:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource dataFromEnum}}" SelectedValue="{Binding Source={x:Static props:UserSettings.Instance}, Path=DefaultCalcMethod}">
```

where the enum items source is got in this way:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="dataFromEnum" MethodName="GetValues" ObjectType="{x:Type sys:Enum}">
        <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
            <x:Type TypeName="calc:Method"/>
        </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
    </ObjectDataProvider>
</ResourceDictionary>
```